# Django 1.6 for_concrete_model explained

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.6

I'm looking at the Django doc 1.6 on [`GenericForeignKeys`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey). I'm confused about this new statement means. Could someone explain?

> `for_concrete_model`
>
> New in Django 1.6.
>
> If `False`, the field will be able to reference proxy models. Default is `True`. This mirrors the `for_concrete_model` argument to `get_for_model()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) are a form of model inheritance.

Previously, a generic foreign key could reference a 'concrete' model (i.e. an original model), but not a proxy model.

The new `concrete_for_model` parameter introduced in [Ticket 17648](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17648) allows you to reference a proxy model if you use `concrete_for_model=False`.